# Does Any Language Have a Delayed Return Mechanism?

Tags: java, return, delay

Is there any language which has a keyword such as `delayedreturn` which allows you to save a value and only return it when a method completes?

For example, something like this (Java syntax):

```
public Integer nullify(Node<Integer> node){

    delayedreturn node.getValue();

    node.setValue(null);

}
```

I know that it's not that much of a space saver. Just curious if anyone deemed it worthy of implementing.

Comment: Here's a somewhat related article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises

Comment: I don't believe you need a special feature to do this, just a temporary value.

Comment: @PeterLawrey True of course, but that's why I used the words "space saver". (Although one line isn't much, unless the object being created has a very long constructor / lots of generics.)

Comment: If you're measuring space in lines, you can always just delete the line breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java actually does have something which accomplishes just what you are asking for, and I've even seen some legitimate uses of it (by Doug Lea, if I'm not mistaken):

```
try { return node.getValue(); } 
finally { node.setValue(null); }
```

In general this is dangerous because an exception thrown from `try` can be masked by another one thrown from `finally`.

Comment: Do finally statements really execute even after a return? The parameters pass and everything? Anyway, it's not exactly what I'm talking about, but if it works, this is a cool trick. (Not one I'd use, but fun to know.)

Comment: `finally` is guaranteed to execute as the very last thing, so even after determining the return value. The trick is dirty in many ways because it messes with the exception mechanism.

Comment: Chris, yes it is.  Check the JLS.

Answer (score 6):

There are no languages like that that I know of. Such a keyword would most likely cause the return value to be stored in a temporary location, which you can already accomplish:

```
public Integer nullify (Node<Integer> node) {
    Integer delayedReturn = node.getValue();
    node.setValue(null);
    return delayedReturn;
}
```

It's essentially the same as what you are asking, just a different syntax than you proposed.

Comment: Ha! Exact same answer but you fixed the 'r' and made it 'R'.

Comment: I think we even added the same comment to eachother's answers.

Comment: This will result in a `NullPointerException` if `value` was already `null`

Comment: Thank you damo, I've updated the answer. Lee's answer addressed that correctly.

Comment: +1 To sure you can have the `return delayedReturn;` in a finally block.

Comment: That depends whether or not you want to swallow an exception thrown by getValue() or setValue(null). I presume the desired behavior of 'delayedreturn' in the OP was to still throw exceptions -- but I'm just guessing, since the keyword doesn't exist.

Comment: "There are no languages like that that I know of". Thanks for le answer. I upvoted yours because of clarity, but selected Marko's because I've never seen his suggestion before (and since most people already know the temp method).

Answer (score 2):

Never seen one. But when you can do this, it doesn't matter much:

```
public Integer nullify(Node<Integer> node){
    Integer delayedreturn = node.getValue();
    node.setValue(null);
    return delayedreturn;
}
```

Comment: Wow, we even picked the same variable name.

Comment: @JasonC You did beat my by 10 seconds or so. Or so I thought. But sorting by 'oldest' seems to say the opposite. Who cares?

Comment: It's OK, it says "1 min ago" now, nobody will ever know.

Comment: Evan started typing his answer 15 minutes before the question was posted. Sir! We're detecting a tachyon particle stream radiating from the SO data ce... *ZZZZZZZZT* (inexplicable exploding console)

Comment: Yep, this is what I already do. I was just curious if any languages streamlined the process.